# why Android live wall paper in not setting? its forcably closing. why?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

i downloaded the Acquarium live wall paper, when i run on eclipse it shows no errors, but in console its is showing the following message

```
                                                Android Launch!
  [2012-05-25 14:55:43 - LiveAquariumWallpaper] adb is running normally.
  [2012-05-25 14:55:43 - LiveAquariumWallpaper] **No Launcher activity found!**
  [2012-05-25 14:55:43 - LiveAquariumWallpaper] **The launch will only sync the application package on the device!**
  [2012-05-25 14:55:43 - LiveAquariumWallpaper] Performing sync
  [2012-05-25 14:55:43 - LiveAquariumWallpaper] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'deepi-8' is available on emulator 'emulator-5556'
  [2012-05-25 14:55:45 - LiveAquariumWallpaper] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
  [2012-05-25 14:55:45 - LiveAquariumWallpaper] \LiveAquariumWallpaper\bin\LiveAquariumWallpaper.apk installed on device
  [2012-05-25 14:55:45 - LiveAquariumWallpaper] Done!
```

why i am getting this message, if i try to set menu-> live wall papers->Aquarium-> set wall paper, not setting, unfortunately closing . why? whats the reason for it? 
      in Logcat: [here](http://www.pastie.org/3965471)

Comment: logcat: [here](http://www.pastie.org/3965471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making use of a big Bitmap which is leading you to Out Of memory. As you can see this line,

```
05-25 15:21:04.276: E/AndroidRuntime(360):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-25 15:21:04.276: E/AndroidRuntime(360):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
05-25 15:21:04.276: E/AndroidRuntime(360):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
05-25 15:21:04.276: E/AndroidRuntime(360):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
```

You  have to find out ways to reduce the Bitmap Size by scaling it or by using a smaller Bitmap.

We have hell a lot of discussion about OOM here. take a look at these and find out a way to reslove it.

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=out+of+memory+android](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=out%20of%20memory%20android)

Comment: hi selva, let me clear a doubt, i have all images(.png/.jpg) in drawable folder. what you mentioned u r link i found some relevant code Bitmap bm;
    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(**filepath**),100, 100, true); and have method private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
      try { ...   }}. here what filepath means?

Comment: File path refer to your sdcard location. If you want to use your res folder images try this, //  bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.angry_tiger), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.angry_tiger).getWidth(), height, true);

Comment: hi selva,i tried scaledBitmap but again it is showing following logct: [here] (http://www.pastie.org/4007164)

Comment: You are running into java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. You have to post the code for help

Answer (score 0):

Your apk is installed properly but it wont show ur output like normal application.so u need to set as livewallper.in real Device if u LongTouch the home Screen it will show wallpapers to set by selecting this one u ll find ur installed wallpaper apk.by selecting that apk u ll see the wallpaper on screen.